# Pivot table in python (Sum of values in column)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pivot-table

I have some problem to generate pivot tables. I try to do this with Python.
Now I have test tables:

Table 1

[image]

I want to do tables that looks like this:

Table 2

[image]

I write code but still have two columns but no sum of this.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


table = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx',0)
print(table.head())
print(pd.pivot_table(table,values=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"],columns=[np.sum]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `Transpose` the dataframe and then sum the columns(axis=1).

Something like this:

```
In [384]: table                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[384]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  2  4
1  1  3  2

In [386]: table.T.sum(axis=1)                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[386]: 
A    2
B    5
C    6
dtype: int64
```

### Updated answer after OP's comment:

If you want to sum only certain columns, do this:

```
In [468]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[468]: 
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G
0  1  2  4  5  6  5  6
1  2  3  2  1  2  3  4

In [469]: df[['C','D','E','F']]                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[469]: 
   C  D  E  F
0  4  5  6  5
1  2  1  2  3

In [471]: df[['C','D','E','F']].T.sum(axis=1)                                                                                                                                                               
Out[471]: 
C    6
D    6
E    8
F    8
dtype: int64
```

Comment: What if I want sum only columns for C - F and printed only this columns?